# Why do we need to use _ilecell at the end of the salesforce Id in the javascript button?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, salesforce-id

Below is the code i used in the button to access a field ID and then the button worked perfectly. Wanted to know what does that `_ilecell` means ?

```
document.getElementById("00N1g000000GzbV**_ilecell**")
```

Comment: You might have more luck if you included more detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had to interact with the fields the way you are. Instead, I use the [API provided by SFDC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm).

I just pulled open a random detail page in a developer org that has very few customizations and all of the fields displayed on the page have _ilecell appended to their ids.

After a bit more time looking at the code, I believe they have to append this suffix as the ID of the field is referenced many times throughout the page. The ilecell suffix is used on the TD element that contains a div whose Id has an ileinner suffix. This ileinner div contains the actual value of the field so you should use this suffix instead.

Id's must be unique so you can't simply use the field ID over and over again (how would JS know which element you wanted?).

**Final Note:**

I believe [javascript buttons are being discontinued](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM) in lightning. Consider [Lightning Alternatives To Javascript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration)